# undefined method `default_locale=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to internacionalize my application made with devise, but i'm struggling in some points. I've installe the i18n gem and created the `devise.pt-BR.yml` file and wrote inside `application.rb`

```
  config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
```

Ok, but when i try to anything inside my application, i get the following error message:

> undefined method `default_locale=' for nil:NilClass
>
> Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/aqueleprojetoprivate/medicos
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in
>   `<class:ApplicationController>'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in`'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in`block
>   in load_file' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in`
>   load_file' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in`
>   load_missing_constant' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
>   app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1:in`'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in`block
>   in load_file' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in`
>   load_file' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in`
>   load_missing_constant' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in`
>   const_get' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in`
>   each' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject' activesupport
>   (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in`constantize'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in`
>   constantize' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `controller_reference'
>   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in`
>   controller' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:41:in `serve' actionpack
>   (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block in serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
>   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in
>   `call' warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
>   warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' warden (1.2.4)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in
>   `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call' rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in
>   `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in`
>   call' activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in
>   `__run_callbacks__' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
>   web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:31:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>   railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app' railties
>   (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call' activesupport
>   (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged' railties (4.2.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call' activesupport (4.2.4)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in
>   `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call' actionpack (4.2.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call' railties (4.2.4)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call' railties (4.2.4)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:165:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in
>   `run'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in`
>   block in start_thread'

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Rails is version 4.2.

If that is the case, you should not use `config.i18n` but `I18n`.
See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#optional-custom-i18n-configuration-setup):

```
# in config/initializers/locale.rb

# tell the I18n library where to find your translations
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

# set default locale to something other than :en
I18n.default_locale = :pt
```

Comment: correct. Thanks. I'm new to rails and i woild like to know What's the most used version of rails?

Comment: i'm sure there are many Rails 3 applications out there, but I recommend going with the newest stable version (as you are doing). Upgrades are very painless these days.

Comment: The example you give is when you use a different file then application.rb. In this case you use a locale initializer, but if you use application.rb then config.i18n.load_path should work. This is also described in the documentation.

Comment: What would be better phrasing then? Since it seems to fix his problem, and `config.i18n.load_path` doesn't work.